# Trouble mapping AWS API Gateway path to HTTP API

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway

I'm having difficulty mapping an AWS Gateway url with path parameters to an HTTP API.

So far, I've been able to do the following:

1. Map a static gateway url to a static beanstalk application url
2. Map a gateway url with path parameters to a lambda function

I want a request to the API Gateway with this url -->
https://[resourceid]-amazonaws.com/[stage-name]config/{id}/raw

to go to this elastic beanstalk url -->
http://[applicationname]-elasticbeanstalk.com/config/{id}/raw

Also, I am using the new AWS Console and I'm not familiar with mapping template syntax

Answer (score 1):

To map a URL from an AWS API Gateway, which has path parameters, to a specific Elastic Beanstalk application URL that also includes these parameters. You've already got experience mapping static URLs and connecting API Gateway with Lambda, so that's a great start!

- Create Resource & Method in API Gateway: Set up a resource for
  `/config/{id}/raw` and a GET method.
- Set Up Integration Request: In the GET method, choose "HTTP" for
  integration type and enter your Elastic Beanstalk URL, like
  `http://[applicationname].elasticbeanstalk.com/config/{id}/raw`.
- Path Parameter Mapping: Ensure {id} in the Elastic Beanstalk URL is
  set to receive the `{id}` from the API Gateway path.
- Deploy API: Deploy your API to the required stage.

That's it! This will map your API Gateway URL with path parameters to your Elastic Beanstalk URL.